# Find the division remainder of a float number Python

Tags: python, floating-point, division

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKKXL.png]

Why 0.03 divide by 0.01, the reminder is 0.01, not zero??

I try 0.3 % 0.1, the result is 0.1. For 3 % 1, the result is zero. Crazy.

Comment: You should go one step deeper. The number corresponding to input/display 0.01 is `"%.25f"%0.01 : '0.0100000000000000002081668'` and for 0.03 `"%.25f"%0.03 : '0.0299999999999999988897770'`

Answer (score 1):

Use `remainder` can avoid this error, as shown below.

```
from math import remainder
remainder(0.03,0.01)
```

Comment: The result is `-1.734723475976807e-18` not really 0 :-)